# get certain cell in tkinter grid

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

This will draw a grid with same picture in every field. If I want to input row=x and col=y ex. x=3 y=2 and change picture only for that cell, how to do it?
Also if, I move that picture one or two fields how to get coordinates from cell where is it?

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#main window

root = Tk()
root.title("toys ")
root.geometry("1000x800")
root.iconbitmap('Images/python.ico')

img1_temp = Image.open("Images/Spikes.png")
img1resized= img1_temp.resize((100,100))
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1resized)

img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Images/Empty.png"))

imgr_temp = Image.open("Images/robot.png")
imgr_resized = imgr_temp.resize((100,100))
img_robot = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgr_resized)

main_canvas = Canvas(root, width=600, height=600,scrollregion = "0 -200 200 0")
main_canvas.pack(pady=70)
cells = []
for r in range(6):
    for c in range(6):
        cells.append(Label(main_canvas, bd=5, height=80, width=80, 
        relief=RIDGE,padx=3, pady=3, image=img2).grid(row=r,column=c))
```

I tried this, but... not good

```
for cell in cells:
    if type(cell) is Label:
        row = 0
        column = 0
        image = img_robot
```

Comment: Note that all the items in `cells` are `None` because they are result of `grid(...)`.

Comment: here`s the whole code. Small game, with spikes and robot. Robot will be put on table by x,y manually added by user. I want to take those values and put robot there. After a few moves if not on spikes, robot should say his coordinates .  THX